Chrome ругается "deceptive site". Что делать и кто виноват?))
Chrome ругается "deceptive site". Что делать и кто виноват?
Я не программист, я - заказчик)
Прошу посмотреть скрины и подсказать в каком направлении искать проблему.
Сайт и место возникновения ошибки (именно после ввода пароля, даже если ввести любые значения):
https://securityupdates.org/auth/



Для начала просканируйте сайт на вирусы и прочую малварь.

Домен менять? Ну или писать в гугл. Я подозреваю, что эти предупреждения по чёрным спискам работают.

Толку было бы больше. если бы был показан адрес сайта.

@SeVlad, вообще-то на скринах есть адрес сайта. Только вот никакого предупреждения на нём у меня нет.

@Qwertiy если бы это был адрес ТСа, то у него такой бы вопрос не мог возникнуть :) Но даже если бы был он - его надо писать руками, а не картинками показывать.

@Qwertiy а вообще это может быть и адрес ТСа.. Очень "интересный" сайт :) https://i.imgur.com/0VtzVMB.jpeg (а в блек-базах чисто)

@SeVlad, whois говорит, что этому сайту меньше 2 недель. Updated Date: 2024-04-30T16:33:58Z
Creation Date: 2024-04-25T16:33:45Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2025-04-25T16:33:45Z

@Qwertiy да пофик что там сейчас в хуизе. Важна история домена. А он существует минимум с 2011г. Мог и 10 лет назад попасть в беклисты. Но в данном случае он чист. А вот то что в индексе яши и что в реальности - уже занимательно..

У тебя похоже дыра в битриксе. Там занимательный скрипт

Нужно обратиться к специалистам по битриксу (это не я.) И не нужно оставлять тут свои контакты - так любой мошенник воспользуется, представившись чужим именем.

Хорошо, большое спасибо
